# make texarea readonly using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my textarea readonly using CSS however not sure how to do it. I have tried following things, none of them seems to work.

I know how to do it using html, but I don't want to do and change the html of all the textarea.

```
readonly:readonly;
```

and

```
readonly:True;
```

and

```
readonly:"readonly";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this using css only, you can try `pointer-events: none;`. However this is not crossbrowser decision

Comment: could you please let me know which browser it works and which it doesn't ?

Answer (score 4):

`readonly` is an HTML attribute rather than a CSS property.

To prevent editing via HTML, add the `readonly` attribute to your `textarea` tag: `<textarea readonly>content!</textarea>`

To prevent editing via CSS, use `pointer-events`:

```
textarea {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will cause the browser to ignore clicks to the element, thus preventing alteration. (There may however be other ways to edit it.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this in HTML:

```
<textarea readonly>
  Your text goes here.......
</textarea>
```